# Sync folder from Windows server to Ubuntu server through FTP

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008, ftp, synchronization

I need to automatically transfer files from windows server over to an Ubuntu server through FTP.

I control the ubuntu server and have no other access to the windows server but through FTP.

I need a command line ftp-sync program in ubuntu to check the ftp-folder on windows every 10 minutes and download all new files there and delete them from the windows server (or move to some other directory like 'completed') when download has been completed over to the ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `curlftps`:

```
apt-get install curlftpfs
```

and create a file `~/.netrc` in the home directory of the user who should run this with the following content:

```
machine ftp.example.com login yourusername password yourpassword
```

Then, write a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /mnt/ftp
curlftpfs ftp.example.com/yourtargetdir /mnt/ftp
rsync -a --delete-after  /mnt/ftp /yourlocaldir
fusermount -u /mnt/ftp
```

and put this script in cron job to run every ten minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/your/script.sh
```